# If an object offers to set a delegate object - do i have to set one?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, delegates

Many Cocoa classes offer to set delegates. Now my rather simple question is: Do I have to set a delegate in this case, or is it optional to set a delegate?

For example i use `NSSharingService`.
It comes with a `delegate` property and if i would set one, i could implement the **NSSharingServiceDelegate Protocol** on this delegate.
If i am not interested in any of the methods in this protocol to be called, do I still have to set the delegate and implement these methods (as empty methods)?
Or is it an option to just not set a delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not always mandatory to set the delegate, but if you do set the delegate it's mandatory to implement the `@required` methods declared in the delegate protocol.

That being said, most of the time setting the delegate it's the right thing to do if you want to build a high quality, robust application.

In the particular case of the `NSSharingService` delegate, I think you should be interested at least in `sharingService:didShareItems:` and `sharingService:didFailToShareItems:error:`, at least for logging these events. But most likely you also want to give some kind of feedback to the user when sharing stuff, to improve user experience.